# lua metatable bug or feature?

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

If I have this construct:

```
a.key = b
```

and both a has a metatable attached and b has a metatable attached. Then b's metatable setter will be called to set key to b. Is this a bug of lua 5.3.0?

EDIT: a and b are strings.

Comment: It seems that  `a`  and `b`  are sharing a metatable or you're misinterpreting the arguments in the newindex handler. You need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tables and full userdata have individual metatables (although multiple
>   tables and userdata can share their metatables). Values of all other
>   types share one single metatable per type; that is, there is one
>   single metatable for all numbers, one for all strings, etc. By
>   default, a value has no metatable, but the string library sets a
>   metatable for the string type (see §6.4).

Answer from the docs. It is a feature: a and b were string and hence shared their metatable.

Comment: How is `a` a string if you have `a.key = b`?

Comment: @YuHao a metatable can be set on any value, just that it may not be an individual metatable. In case of strings it is shared among all the strings. Hence, a string may have properties and other meta-features.

Comment: Show what you mean in the code of your own question. No one can see `a` and `b` are strings from `a.key = b`.

Comment: @YuHao it was done via the C API, hence I couldn't paste the code. There would be too much of it. Nor did I indeed do `a.key = b`, the equivalent of that was done via the C API. I'll revise my question and state that a and b were strings.